# Get background image's aspect ratio in jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, background, background-image

The client has a WordPress based website using the Theme Hiker. On **[this](http://ascetic.rol.ro/slander/)** page, there is a gallery that, instead of inline images, uses background images.

I need to determine the value of those images *with over height ratio*. If the ratio is smaller than 1, add `background-size: contain` to each slide (a list element) that meets that condition.

I made this function:

```
function setBackgroundSize() {
    var $sliderItem = $(".full-photos li");
    $sliderItem.each(function(){
      var imageSrc = $(this).data('image-src');
      imageSrc.replace(/url\((['"])?(.*?)\1\)/gi, '$2')
      .split(',')[0];
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = imageSrc;
      var width = image.width,
      height = image.height,
      ratio = width/height;
      console.log(ratio);
      if (ratio < 1) {
        $(this).css('background-size', 'contain');
      }
    });
}
$(window).load(setBackgroundSize());
```

The problem is that it only works after the page has loaded, I **refresh it**. What's wrong with the script? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(window).load(setBackgroundSize());` is executing the `setBackgroundSize` function immediately (before the load event occurs). Pass a reference to the function instead:

```
$(window).load(setBackgroundSize);
```

or

```
$(window).load(function() { setBackgroundSize(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can run it like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() { setBackgroundSize(); });
```

I hope I understood you correctly.